# Android: Handling touch events for OpenGL-ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, event-handling, touch

While implementing touch events I noticed that I couldn't update a variable in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` case to be "received" in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` case. The variable just seemed to go out of scope. (Code below)

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();
    boolean Finger_Down = false;
    float   PowerBar    = 0;
    float   CurrentPowerLevel   = 0;

    switch (e.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            PowerBar=1;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mRenderer.mPlayer.Tx-=PowerBar;             
            break;     
    }
    return true;
}
```

The purpose of the code is to simply raise the power level in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` case, and have it execute the intensity in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` case.

I can perform the behaviors individually, ie:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
mRenderer.mPlayer.Tx-=0.01f;                
break;
```

or:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
mRenderer.mPlayer.Tx-=0.01f;                
break;
```

But not otherwise as intuitively expected. Is there another event methodology that I should be doing/overlooking?

EDIT:

This behavior continues for touch listener:(below)

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float Foo=0;
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Foo=0.1f;
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                mRenderer.mPlayer.Tx=Foo;
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a scope issue, Foo was originally being declared and initialized as `float Foo = 0;` within the `onTouch()` implementation. When the event was consumed, the function would return and no more events accessed. Upon the next iteration, `onTouch()` is again called, and `Foo` initialized to `0`.

```
...

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float Foo=0;
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Foo-=0.1f;
                return true;
            }
```

Declaring `Foo` outside of the `onTouch()` function resolved the issue.

Comment: That's what I was going to say first, but I figured you wanted it to do that?

Comment: Haha, after seeing the same code for a while I just couldn't "get" why it wasn't working and everything was "perfect".

Answer (score 0):

Use:
    return true;
rather than break; and substitute return false where you return true;

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, I replaced the break statement with return true, and had the function return false. FYI, it's not a touch listener, just a touch event.

Comment: Ok, I implemented a Touch Listener for the view and it exhibits the same behavior. I can set actions per `MotionEvent`, but as soon as another event response is set, everything becomes unresponsive. I've included my Surface Touch Listener implementation above.